# Passing Backbone collection to Spring

Tags: java, spring, backbone.js

So I have a Backbone collection and a bunch of fields in a form that I would like to do a $.ajax call on (probably a GET). In order to access this data, what should I put in the data field for the $.ajax function and what annotation(is it @RequestParam?) should I use to get the collection and the components of the form out in Java Spring?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Spring directly but I don't think it should be any different then accepting JSON or HTTP Form data or XML for that matter.

You could simply format your data as key-value pairs and send it: (it'll need to be parsed as a form in Spring)

```
$.ajax({
    data:'var1=value1&var2=value2'
});
```

or just send a JSON object and set the contentType to JSON (or build an XML if you wish) It's totally upto you.

Depending on what format you select you must set the `contentType` appropriately. You can read more about the ajax properties [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)